# No sound, but only from one of the soundcards

Tags: audio, manjaro, dock-station

Yesterday I have turned on my laptop and found out that I get no sound from my soundcard.

The symptoms of the problem are:

- KDE shows the device as normal, even the sound level indicator goes up and down while playing music
- Every application sees this device as normal
- I can control the volume as same as before, but no sound
- The sound works just fine on the other soundcards

What I have tried

- All the classics: Replugging the jack
- Reseating the soundcard (since it’s a part of a USB-C docking station)
- Restarting the pulseaudio
- Rebooting the whole laptop
- Playing sound from another OS (on Windows 10 worked without problems)

If you guys have any idea what might cause this, I would strongly appreciate any kind of response as same as I can provide any additional logs of my system.

KDE 5.21.5 on Manjaro 21.0.7

One thing I have noticed is that in alsamixer I only seem to have capture and not playback like it is on the screenshot, I hope it will help
[image: Alsamixer screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So.... Thanks everybody for their response :smiley:

For those who could have the same issue, here is my fix:

I am using HP 455 G7 laptop with DELL WD15 dock. After booting up the live version of linux being ready to reinstall the whole system I noticed the audio wasn't working either. So what I did is I first unplugged the USB-C cable from the laptop and then unplugged the dock from it's power (My speakers connected to the dock popped a bit). Then I reconnected the power adapter back to the dock and then the UCB-C cable back to the laptop. Then I did a reboot and everything seems to work fine somehow. It's quite strange, since I have completly changed the settings of pulseaudio, but it seems to work just fine, so as long as it's working I'll leave it like that.